# Oracle Query comparing two table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables `T1` and `T2`.

`T1` having records like A,B,C,D
`T2` having records like A,B,D,E

Now out of the query should be C when we compare both tables as C is not available in `T2`

Please help here..

Comment: Guess you need a select statement

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can use the `minus` set operator:

```
select t1.*
from t1
minus
select t2.*
from t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use an inner join, this will return everything that both tables have in common, so:

```
SELECT T1.* FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
```

Comment: The result should be displayed only from T1

Comment: I've updated the query to return all from T1, you shouldn't use * though, specify all columns one by one

Answer (score 0):

> Another way of achieving this would be:

```
SELECT
    C1
FROM
    T1
WHERE
    C1 NOT IN (
        SELECT
            C1
        FROM
            T2
    );
```